# How to get an environment as a variable?

Tags: r

I would like to find environments and get them as variables. My goal is to be able to do some subsequent calls to `sys.source` even though I lost track of the environment as a variable, but I know it's name.
Example:

```
MyFuns <- attach(NULL, name = 'Myfuns')
sys.source('myFunctions.R', envir = Myfuns)
rm('MyFuns')
any(grepl('MyFuns', search())) # It is there
sys.source('oneMoreFunction.R', envir = Myfuns) # Will not work because the variable as been suppressed.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've attached the environment, you can find it again with `as.environment`:

```
attach(NULL, name = "Myfuns")
assign("a", 1, env = as.environment("Myfuns"))
get("a", env = as.environment("Myfuns"))

sys.source('myFunctions.R', envir = as.environment("Myfuns"))
```

You may also want to consider making a package and then using `devtools::load_all()` to load the code - it will also load code, compile C code, respect `NAMESPACE`, load other required packages etc.